# Newbie here :WAVES: Just need a bit of help, simple for you guys! :P

Tags: javascript

I'm new and new to Javascript. I'm learning what I can but I'm struggling with functions.

Iv edited my question and have taken knowledge from the answer given.
I have created a basic miles per gallon calculator, below that produces a number from the given values, I would now like it to give me an overall journey cost if I declare the price of the fuel in £ per gallon.

I have tried several ways to no avail and just seem to make a mess, any help would be really appreciated. I have commented out the fuelPrice just as a reference for what I was going to use, Its a const because I was going to have the price fixed for now.

Kind Regards
Kameleonic

```html
//MPG Calculator

//const fuelPrice = 5.31 // £ per gallon.

function calcMpg(miles, gallons) {
  const mpg = Math.trunc(miles / gallons);
  console.log(`Jake had an average mpg of ${mpg}`);
  return mpg;
}

calcMpg(125, 3); // Milles travelled, Amount in gallon to re-fill tank.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. Of course filled is greater than 0. What is the point of that check?

```
const filled = 126 / gallons;
if (filled > 0) {
```

2. Then you made a recursion call without passing the arguments. Since the "filled" is always positive, the function will call itself (recursion) all the time, so the rest of the function never runs. And because of the undefined arguments, 126 / undefined is undefined, so NaN.

```
const filled = calcMpg();
```

3. Even if this line of code runs, you put the result into an array, but you used it as a string.

```
const overallCost = [gallons * cost]
console.log(`The journey cost a toal of £${overallCost}`);
```

4. What is this line of code doing. It's not changing anything. It's not assigned a variable.

```
Math.trunc(calcMpg(3));
```

5. You called the function with a lack of arguments. BTW, where is cost? You never defined or calculate.

```
calcMpg(2.76);
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, thanks for explaining were Iv gone wrong, It may seem pretty stupid to you but to me this was a whole hour of brain melt... I confused myself so much I didn't know which way to turn.

Comment: It's not stupid. We all have started from somewhere.

Comment: I have edited the question with an updated code that I have written, would you care to explain if my request is possible. Thanks.